# .NET MVC 4 route map and Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I got struggled in such a problem that when i have a route map configuration like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Merchandise",
            url: "Merchandise/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I got "hxxp://site.com/Merchandise/Controller/Action/1" from @Html.Action("Action","Controller", new { Id = "1"}) where "hxxp://site.com/Controller/Action/1" was expected.

If route map configured to

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Merchandise",
            url: "Merchandise/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

then I got 404 when trying an Url like "hxxp://site.com/Merchandise/Controller" with Merchandise being not a Controller ("hxxp://site.com/Merchandise/Controller/Action/1" is OK BTW). How can i solve this contradiction? What i want is that "Merchandise" here act as an role of category but not a controller.

Comment: Merchandise in your case can be called an area. Refer Areas in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Merchandise in your case can be called an area. Refer Areas in ASP.NET MVC**
As per design of routes if you have any custom routes that should be defined before the default route. Because that is the order in which the urls are decoded to routes. So in your first case you have your custom route defined before the default route and hence it works correctly while in the second case the default route is defined first.

Comment: Nice advice,thank's a lot.But this is still not quite fit to my situation.I try the solution below witch fix the 404 and still act correctly in Html.Action (or in Html.BeginForm etc.).But it's added an unnecessary .mvc extension to the controller name in Url.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Merchandise",
            url: "Merchandise/{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: What is your question? Do you want Merchadise to be a part of your URL or not?

Comment: Yes I want Merchandise to be a part of my URL. But the Area solution seems to be heavyweight.What i want is only a custom route mapping.